# Bower install not latest version

Tags: bower

I have package `bootstrap-calendar`

In `bower.json` it is version `0.2.0-RC` and I even updated it to `0.2.0`. But no matter what when you run

```
$> bower install bootstrap-calendar
```

it attempts to install version 0.0.9 which is earliest version. I cleaned cache but no success. What can I do that on bower install command latest package would be installed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is anything you are doing incorrectly. The package installs for me as `0.0.9` and the js file is listed as `0.1`.  I think the package is just not correct and needs to be mentioned on the issues section of Github, which I did.